# Javascript Worker losing properties

Tags: javascript, prototype, cluster-analysis, web-worker

I'm working on a webApp which shows clustered lightning occurrences on a map (so a huge cluster is like a thunderstorm formation).

To avoid 'freezing' the user interface, i'm using a Javascript Worker to perform the clustering. The problem happens when the algorithm finishes, because it returns a custom object which 'loses' some properties after i send it to the main page:

```
//inside Worker.js
var cluster = new DBSCAN(e.data.params).run();
self.postMessage({"cluster": cluster});
```

The *cluster*  object is basically an array of *GeoPoint* objects, so:

```
cluster[0]
```

is a GeoPoint object like this

```
function GeoPoint(lat, lng){
    this.lat_ = lat;
    this.lng_ = lng;
}
GeoPoint.prototype.lat = function(){ return this.lat_;}
GeoPoint.prototype.lng = function(){ return this.lng_;}
```

When i send this object with `self.postMessage` i lose the `lat()` and `lng()` functions, **which i need** to draw the polygons. The `lat_` and `lng_` properties are intact though.

What can i do to overcome this? Right now i'm simply looping over the results and reconstructing the `GeoPoint` objects, it works but seems very bad.

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: I need those functions because the drawing code will perform a sorting on the lat lon points, before it can calculate the convex hull.

Comment: No, that's just what you need to do. Functions cannot be transported across the worker boundary.

Comment: Why do you need those `lat`/`lng` methods anyway? Would a plain object `{lat:…, lng:…}` not be much simpler?

Comment: The framework which draws the Polygon will call those methods, that's why i need them.

Comment: Can you recreate the functions on the other side of the boundary? It's not ideal but the functions are simple and it would probably get it working pretty quickly.

Comment: What do you mean? I recreating the GeoPoint objects in the main page, calling new GeoPoint() for each result, this 'reconstructs' the functions i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can i do to overcome this?

Nothing - the [cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm) used by `postMessage` does not transport prototypes and functions. Reconstructing them on the other side is necessary.

> Right now i'm simply looping over the results and reconstructing the GeoPoint objects, it works but seems very bad.

No, that's what needs to be done:

```
var newCluster = messageData.cluster.map(function(likeapoint) {
    var point = new GeoPoint();
    for (p in likeapoint)        // maybe a static list of copied property names
        point[p] = likeapoint[p];// is faster, but not as flexible
    return point;
})

// since all properties are settable as arguments in this specific case:
var newCluster = messageData.cluster.map(function(likeapoint) {
    return new GeoPoint(likeapoint.lat_, likeapoint.long_);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `postMessage` uses the structured clone algorithm. Functions and prototypes are not transferred :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FThe_structured_clone_algorithm

What you can try after receiving your data is change the prototype of the received objects :

```
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    data.forEach(function(p) {
        p.__proto__ = GeoPoint.prototype; // That seems to work, but I'm really not sure if this is standard and compatible with all browsers !
    });
};
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working. I got *Object #<Object> has no method 'lat'*

Comment: Obviously that doesn't works. I don't know why. I'll never completely understand prototypes ...

Comment: Try replacing `p.prototype = GeoPoint.prototype;` with `p.__proto__ = GeoPoint.prototype;`. That seems to work, but I'm really not sure if this is standard and compatible with all browsers !

Comment: Assigning to `p.prototype` does never work. Assigning to `p.__proto__` does not work in the half of the clients.

Comment: @Bergi p.__proto__ worked, but it's now cross browser?

Comment: @Fernando: Yes, it's nonstandard and does most notably not work in IE